# Calculate hash value for UDP packets in NS2

Tags: java, networking, hash, ns2, ns-3

My project is to create a sample network in NS2 and forward packets randomly within the nodes. Whenever a packet passes through a particular node the packets hash value should be calculated for the packets and stored within the node through which the packet passes or save them as a file separately (with one file for each node). I have written the code for the network creation and packet flow in NS2. But not sure how to implement hashing of packets in NS2. As of now i have read the trace file in Java and considered each row as a string to calculate MD5 hash in Java code. But i need to implement this dynamically within NS2 itself. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use in this case HashClassifier (C++ side) or any derived class such as DestHashClassifier, FidHashClassifier, SrcDestHashClassifier, or SrcDestFidHashClassifier, you can also use tcl side with classifier/Hash/Dest, classifier/Hash/Fid, classifier/Hash/SrcDest, or classifier/Hash/SrcDestFid